# how to do this using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi could someone please explain to me to how i can accomplish this using ajax so there is no page refresh. I am new to using ajax and jquery in general and any help and explanation would be great.

This is my php code.

```
<div class="recentwork">
<div class="imgholderfloat">
<?php
include 'process/connect.php';
$small_path = "/work/small/";
$large_path = "/work/large/";
$full_path  = "/work/full/";


$per_page = 3;
$pages_query = "SELECT id FROM projects";
$pages_result = mysqli_query( $link, $pages_query );
$pages = ceil(mysqli_num_rows($pages_result) / $per_page);

if ($_GET['page'] > $pages) {
    $page = 1;
} else {
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
}
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;



$query = " SELECT * FROM projects INNER JOIN orders ON orders.id = projects.order_id LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$result = mysqli_query( $link , $query );
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);                               

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<div class="imgholder"><a href="'.$full_path.''.
    $row['filename'].'"><img src="'.$small_path .''.$row['filename'].'" /></a><div class="largeimg"><a href="'.$full_path.''.$row['filename'].'"><img src="'.$large_path.''.$row['filename'].'" /></a></div>
<div class="details">
<p><span class="red">Theme</span>: '.$row['theme'].'</p>
<p><span class="red">Budget</span>: '.$row['budget'].'</p>
<p><span class="red">Type</span>: '.$row['type'].'</p>
<p><span class="red">Misc</span>: '.$row['misc'].'</p>
</div>
</div>
';
}
if ($pages > 1 && $page < $pages) {
    echo '<span class="morebtn" ><a href="?page='. $page= $page + 1 .'" >MORE</a></span>';
} 
else {
    echo '<span class="morebtn" ><a href="?page='. $page= $page - 1 .'" >BACK</a></span>';
}
?>

</div>
</div>
```

So basically its a simple pagination displaying divs which hold pictures etc retrieved from a database. How do i send the particular get statement via ajax so that the next set of divs is updated without page refresh. I have attempted it by myself but could not figure it out.

Thanks again.

Ok so this is as far as i can get. How do i get about displaying what is retrieved? I have looked on the internet but there is so many different ways of doing this i cant understand which and why you would do it a particular way.

```
$("a#morebutton").click(function() {
  e.preventDefault();   
  $.ajax({  
  type: "GET",  
  url: index.php+$('a#morebutton').attr('href') ,
}); 
e.preventDefault();   
});
```

Comment: You would probably get better responses if you showed what you tried.

Comment: well i would be i got rid of it cause it wasnt working but basically i was using the .ajax function of jquery and attempting to pass the get variable via the a tags href attribute to the index page, But i wasnt working.

Comment: A GET call in Ajax is simply a URL with the GET keys/values appended. Try hardcoding it and see what happens. You should have a way of returning snippets of your markup as well; you don't need to return the entire HTML, just what is replacing what is on the page.

Comment: ill give it another go and post what i get

Comment: I don't see an ANCHOR with a class `morebutton` on your code above. Should that be `a#morebtn`?

Answer (score 1):

From reading your code, I assume this is what you want:

```
$(".morebtn a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get("index.php"+$(this).attr("href"), function(result) {
        $(".imgholderfloat").html(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: hi this seems to be doing exactly what i want but, its reloading the whole page into the .imgholder div how would i go about changing it so that it only reload the contents of that div.

Comment: nvm got it working, didnt realise that you  can only have the information you wish to return in an ajax call as it grabs the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes more sense to demonstrate the concepts behind how to change an image using a GET request in Ajax. How you accommodate doing this in your code is a matter of how you organize your code, but it can nevertheless be done in a couple of different ways.

Below, I will demonstrate a method to return an HTML snippet with the `<img .../>` to replace the current image and handle errors, the first/last/previous/next concerns, and so forth. This is meant to show you how you *may* do it in an abstract case; how you do it in the end with your code will ultimately be up to you. Make sure and read the comments in the code below for explanations of what I'm doing.

To see the below in action, see: http://jfcoder.com/test/getimages.php

**NOTE**: I do not send all of the HTML until after I have determined the snippet. This allows me to handle both requests with one PHP script. You can, however, do this with two different scripts.

```
<?php 

// My ad hoc array of images. You of course will be 
// generating this list from a database call.

$images = array(
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/087882_cf786e35-by-Roger-May.jpg',
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/173865_d45f46f7-by-dave-challender.jpg',
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/188798_e4bc708f-by-Stephen-McKay.jpg',
    'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/205765_f6ccbfdb-by-Stephen-G-Taylor.jpg'
);

// I use a switch to determine full html or just a
// snippet to return. Note, it defaults to full.

switch ($_GET['type']) {
    case 'snippet': 
        $type = 'snippet';
        break;
    default:
        $type = 'full';
}

// Determine the current, first, and last ids.

$imgid = (int) $_GET['img'];
$first = 0;
$last = count($images) - 1;

// If it's not real, reset to the beginning photo.

if (!$images[$imgid]) {
    $imgid = 0;
}

// Here I determine what the previous and last img ids
// will be.

$previous = ($imgid < 1 ? $last : $imgid - 1);
$next = ($imgid >= $last+1 ? 0 : $imgid + 1);

// If I just need to return a snippet, then do that and
// exit. This prevents the full code from returning,
// and does so based on the GET `type` value provided.

if ($type == 'snippet') {
    echo "<img class='view' src='{$images[$imgid]}'/>";
    exit;
}

// This will output the full page. Note, it also
// accounts for when the Ajax produces an error, since
// it will respond correctly to a URL with no `type`
// provided and with an `img` value.

echo <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.browse').click(function(){
        that = $(this);
        // I use the `rel` attribute to store image-
        // related data. Each ANCHOR has the reference
        // to the imgid it needs to request the correct
        // image snippet.
        var imgid = that.attr('rel');
        // I need this for errors. This allows me to
        // show the image by bypassing the Ajax call when
        // it doesn't work correctly.
        var href = that.attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            // Note, `get` is default, but I provided it
            // for demonstration purposes and to make it
            // clear this is what is happening.
            type: 'get',
            // Note the `type=snippet` part.
            url: 'getimages.php?type=snippet&img='+imgid,
            // What to do when the Ajax call appears to 
            // complete successfully.
            success: function(data){
                // If the server didn't respond with an
                // `<img .../>` tag, send the browser to
                // the `href` instead. 
                if (data.indexOf('<img') == -1) {
                    window.location = href;
                }
                // I'm going to replace the image with the
                // new image I just got.
                $('.view').replaceWith(data);
                // The bits that manipulate the current
                // page's values for next and previous.
                // Note the use of the `rel` tag here.
                var first = $('#first').attr('rel');
                var last = $('#last').attr('rel');
                var previous = $('#previous').attr('rel') - 1;
                var next = $('#next').attr('rel') - 0 + 1;
                if (previous < 0) previous = last;
                if (next > last || next == last) next = 0;
                $('#previous').attr('rel', previous);
                $('#next').attr('rel', next);
            },
            // Again, if the Ajax call errors out, I simply
            // send the browser to the url found in the `href`.
            error: function(){
                window.location = href;
            }
        });
        // Cancel the browser following the `href` tag.
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img class="view" src="{$images[$imgid]}"/>
<p>
 <a class="browse" id="first" rel="$first" href="?img=$first">First</a>
 <a class="browse" id="previous" rel="$previous" href="?img=$previous">Previous</a>
 <a class="browse" id="next" rel="$next" href="?img=$next">Next</a>
 <a class="browse" id="last" rel="$last" href="?img=$last">Last</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

?>
```

What the browser will see when visiting http://jfcoder.com/test/getimages.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.browse').click(function(){
        that = $(this);
        // I use the `rel` attribute to store image-
        // related data. Each ANCHOR has the reference
        // to the imgid it needs to request the correct
        // image snippet.
        var imgid = that.attr('rel');
        // I need this for errors. This allows me to
        // show the image by bypassing the Ajax call when
        // it doesn't work correctly.
        var href = that.attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            // Note, `get` is default, but I provided it
            // for demonstration purposes and to make it
            // clear this is what is happening.
            type: 'get',
            // Note the `type=snippet` part.
            url: 'getimages.php?type=snippet&img='+imgid,
            // What to do when the Ajax call appears to 
            // complete successfully.
            success: function(data){
                // If the server didn't respond with an
                // `<img .../>` tag, send the browser to
                // the `href` instead. 
                if (data.indexOf('<img') == -1) {
                    window.location = href;
                }
                // I'm going to replace the image with the
                // new image I just got.
                $('.view').replaceWith(data);
                // The bits that manipulate the current
                // page's values for next and previous.
                // Note the use of the `rel` tag here.
                var first = $('#first').attr('rel');
                var last = $('#last').attr('rel');
                var previous = $('#previous').attr('rel') - 1;
                var next = $('#next').attr('rel') - 0 + 1;
                if (previous < 0) previous = last;
                if (next > last || next == last) next = 0;
                $('#previous').attr('rel', previous);
                $('#next').attr('rel', next);
            },
            // Again, if the Ajax call errors out, I simply
            // send the browser to the url found in the `href`.
            error: function(){
                window.location = href;
            }
        });
        // Cancel the browser following the `href` tag.
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img class="view" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/087882_cf786e35-by-Roger-May.jpg"/>
<p>
 <a class="browse" id="first" rel="0" href="?img=0">First</a>
 <a class="browse" id="previous" rel="3" href="?img=3">Previous</a>

 <a class="browse" id="next" rel="1" href="?img=1">Next</a>
 <a class="browse" id="last" rel="3" href="?img=3">Last</a>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And what my `$.ajax()` will see from http://jfcoder.com/test/getimages.php?type=snippet&img=1 (based on the link clicked and the image being viewed):

```
<img class='view' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/173865_d45f46f7-by-dave-challender.jpg'/>
```

Comment: ok i am beginning to understand things right up to the point of success. On success how exactly are we to manage what is displayed? For example when i pass the url it is returning a whole page instead of just the contents of the div. How do i tell ajax to just replace the contents of the .imgholder div without placing the whole new page inside the div.

Answer (score -1):

In conjuction with the use of jQuery, you could try something along the lines of;

```
$("a#morebutton").click(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var result_target=$('#imgholder');
    xhr.open("get", "index.php"+this.href, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300){ 
                $(result_target).html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }           
    };
    xhr.send(null);
});
```

Thats purely off the top of my head, I use this format for all my own XHR calls, may need some tweaking to get it running as you wish.